# "Not a constructor" error with library and angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Im trying to build an Angular application for a chessgame. I want to use the library chess.js https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js/blob/master/README.md with the types declared in https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/chess.js
But whenever i run the application theres an error on runtime.

I've installed the packages through npm with

```
npm install --save chess.js @types/chess.js
```

And in the service that uses the library i've got this relevant code:

```
import {Chess, ChessInstance} from "chess.js"

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GameService {

 private chess: ChessInstance = new Chess()

 constructor() {}
 ...
}
```

The error i get is:

```
core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: chess_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.Chess is not a constructor
TypeError: chess_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.Chess is not a constructor
```

I've also tried importing it as:

```
import * as Chessjs from "chess.js"

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GameService {

 private chess: Chessjs.ChessInstance = new Chessjs.Chess()

 constructor() {}
 ...
}
```

To no success.

I've also tried declaring chess.js from my app.module.ts, but that seems to be the wrong way about importing non-module scripts

Any help would be widely appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't get it to work with the typings because `Chess` is not defined as a `class` but as a `const`

so first uninstall types:

```
npm uninstall --save @types/chess.js
```

and then use it like this.

`import * as Chess from "chess.js`

`chess:any = new Chess();`

the only issue is that you won't have the types (tested and working)

**UPDATE**

based on this [answer](https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js/issues/208#issuecomment-483713144) with modifications, so your editor recognizes the types, you could do with the types installed

```
import { ChessInstance } from 'chess.js'

ChessReq:any = require('chess.js');
Chess:ChessInstance = new this.ChessReq();
```

then use `Chess.header()` for example with the types appearing on your editor

(tested and working too)

Comment: You're a super hero!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Also I advice you to use it in dev mode and switch back to import without types when building. I've been looking around on the net and apperently `require` is more a node.js type of thing.

Answer (score 6):

None of the other answers worked for me in all environments (browser, Jest, VSCode).

This is how I fixed it:

```
import * as ChessJS from "chess.js";

const Chess = typeof ChessJS === "function" ? ChessJS : ChessJS.Chess;

const chess = new Chess();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import it like this

```
import * as Chess from 'chess.js';
```

and use it like:

```
const chess: Chess = new Chess();
```

Comment: I've tried importing it as that (The bottom code-snippet in my OP) and i still get the same errors. Are you initialising `const chess: Chess = new Chess();` outside the service? In that case i get this error: `ERROR in src/app/game.service.ts(123,13): error TS2339: Property 'chess' does not exist on type 'GameService'.`

Comment: You can check the implementation here: https://github.com/supertorpe/chessendgametraining/blob/master/src/app/position/position.page.ts#L11

Answer (score 0):

I'm using chess.js version 0.10.3 and I found that @yazantahhan was partially correct. The following works for me. Just make sure the path to your file is correct as it may differ from mine.

```
import * as Chess from './chess';
const chess = new Chess();
```